# What do you call the process immediately after peeing?

Tags: word-choice

Despite a provoking title, I am looking for a word, phrase or *eloquent* sentence to describe the process a male performs after taking a piss, that is, shaking off remaining pee off the tip of his penis. I apologize for being vague, and I am sure you're getting the drift.

Comment: Given the topic, I hope I won't get flamed for a little facetiousness. Those who have attended a British public school will know that shaking it more than twice is called masturbation >;-)

Comment: Any comment as to why you chose one -1 answer over a +8 one?

Comment: "If you shake it more than twice, you're playing with it."

Answer (score 22):

Only word I have ever heard is Shake - as in the well known proverb:

> No matter how you shake and dance, the
>   last few drops go in your pants

Comment: +1. This has a verbatim Turkish version: "Ne kadar sallarsan salla, donuna düşer son damla".

Comment: German: "Da hilft kein Schütteln und kein Klopfen, immer in die Hose geht der letzte Tropfen". @Mehper.

Comment: It is one of those eternal truths that simply gets translated. In this particular case I think it was NOT translated into Danish because of the difficulty of rhyming with drops or trousers ;)

Comment: Russian: "Сколько не тряси, а последняя капля всегда упадет на ботинок"

Comment: Sigh. Men. Y'all do know there's this newfangled invention called "toilet paper", right? :D

Comment: "You can shake it in your hand, you can slam it on the wall.  But until you get it in your pants, that last drop will not fall."

Comment: @Martha - Sigh. Women and their lack of anatomy knowledge - have a look at wikipedia male anatomy. The drop we are discussing is not wipe-able.

Comment: Toilet paper?? Is this not the job for which underpants were designed? Or maybe some imagine bigger drops?

Comment: @Jasper You mean you fold it up like an inlay and cellotape it to the crotch of your underpants?

Comment: In Holland there are no toilet paper dispensers next to the urinoirs.

Comment: Your choices are to stand there in a stall and wait for all the right valves and sphincters to relax in order to catch it with toilet paper, or accept a couple of drops making it into the underwear.

Comment: Just wanted to add the version I learned as a kid that, imo, has a bit better meter: "No matter how you shake or how you dance, the last drops end up in your pants."

Comment: For a good meter you need to lose the second "how you". Da-da da-da da-da da-da, da-da da-da da-da da da.

Answer (score 8):

The best phrase I've heard for the process is "shaking the dew off the lily."

Comment: Cute. - I am sure Urban Dictionary have more, less elegant;

Answer (score 5):

Well, I would refer to it as personal hygiene.

Comment: Except that anyone counting _that_ as hygiene is seriously delusional

Answer (score 2):

The term I grew up with (in Baltimore) nd have heard in other generations and another part of the country (Colorado) is "wean." I think "shake" is more common; I have heard it more in popular culture.

Answer (score 1):

I went to a bar once where the toilets were labelled "Drip dry" and "Flip dry"...